# apache server serves some pages with upper case UTF-8 and others with lower case utf-8 charset header

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, content-type

I am using `MAMP` to host `php` pages over and `apache server`. In my root directory I have a `.htaccess` file to do some rewrites and other things including adding charsets to the headers of certain files like so:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .css .js
```

Now this code is working fine but I have an issue that is really annoying.

The page `test.php` returns a bunch of html which contains links to some `.css` and `.js` files. Now when I call up the `test.php` file over my browser it returns the following in the response header for each file:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
text/css; charset=utf-8
application/javascript; charset=utf-8
```

I really don't understand why it return the charset in upper case for `html` but in lower case for all other content types. This is not a severe problem of functionality but it really bothers me. To solve this I tried to include the ending `.html` in the `AddCharset` like so:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .css .js .html
```

But this does not change anything, it still returns the the charset for the `text/html` file in user case. Could anyone tell me how to make the server return either consistently upper or lower case charset headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying around to see where the `charset` header was actually set, I discovered that `PHP` outputs a charset automatically so to change the `UTF-8` to `utf-8` you need to change the `Charset` in the `php.ini` file. This fixed the problem.